# How to access nested stl elements?

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following code:

```
set< vector<int> > set_of_things;
vector<int> triplet(3);

//set_of_things.push_back(stuff) - adding a number of things to the set
```

How do I now iterate through the set and print all elements?

The set is a collection of triplets so the output should look like:

```
1 2 3 
3 4 5
4 5 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use iterators:

```
for ( std::set<vector<int> >::iterator it = set_of_things.begin() ; 
      it != set_of_things.end() ; 
      it++ )
{
   // *it is a `vector<int>`
}
```

In C++11 you can use `auto` instead of `std::set<vector<int> >::iterator`.

If you're not modifying the iterator, you should use a `const_iterator` instead.

Comment: so *it[0], *it[1], *it[2] should be the elements in a set? This does not work for me

Comment: @c0smikdebris I didn't say that. `*it` is the element (of type `vector`)

Comment: @c0smikdebris Of course nobody actually frees you of understanding such fundamental things like pointer/iterator dereferenciation and operator precedence.

Answer (score 5):

This is straight-forward with the new range-based `for` loops that were introduced in C++11:

```
for (auto const & v : set_of_things)
{
    for (auto it = v.cbegin(), e = v.cend(); it != e; ++it)
    {
        if (it != v.cbegin()) std::cout << " ";
        std::cout << *it;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

If you don't mind a trailing space:

```
for (auto const & v : set_of_things)
{
    for (auto const & x : v)
    {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Or use [the pretty printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers):

```
#include <prettyprint.hpp>
#include <iostream>

std::cout << set_of_things << std::endl;
```

If you have an older compiler, you will have to spell both iterations out in terms of iterators.

Comment: @Jon: Or perhaps the "legacy-C++" requirement should be explicit in the question? :-)

Comment: Point taken, but when the goal is to provide correct, practical and educational solutions then IMHO the onus is on the more knowledgeable party. :-)